# Clonar DataSet (TZQuery) no Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, postgresql, dataset, zeos

Olá, tenho uma aplicação em delphi que faz o seguinte: Faz uma consulta no banco PostGreSQL utilizando os componentes Zeos TZQuery/TZConnection, em seguida percorre o resultado gravando-o em outra tabela, tabela essa com colunas idênticas as das colunas geradas da consulta anterior.

Funciona, porém, a quantidade de registros é muito grande e percorrer todos esses registros 1 a 1 leva muito tempo. Eis que eu resolvi dividir esse trabalho de percorrer o DataSet utilizando threads, mas parei em um problema que é o seguinte:

Não consigo criar novas instâncias da tabela (DataSet), sendo assim não consigo trabalhar o paralelismo. Alguém tem uma ideia de como resolver isso?

Trecho de como estou executando e como tentei executar respectivamente:

```
qry := TZQuery.Create(nil);
qry := DM.Qry_Levantamento;
--------------
qry := TZQuery.Create(nil);
qry.Assign(DM.Qry_Levantamento);
```

Também pensei em fazer tudo isso por Query, mas ainda não levei isso adiante pois não sei se dá pra aplicar esse paralelismo SQL.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia Rafael.
Se entendi corretamente o que você quer.. :) uma das soluções seria usar um comando direto de sql.. Ficaria assim ..:

```
Insert into TABELA_DESTINO Select * from TABELA_ORIGEM  Where TABELA_ORIGEM.CAMPO = 'XXX'
```

Testei esse comando no PARADOX e no MYSQL, funcionou perfeitamente e rápido.
Qualquer duvida é só falar.
Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.. :)

Comment: Funcionou bem melhor do que eu esperava, sempre bom pedir um conselho depois de bater cabeça atoa... Muito obrigado!